# How can i reuse a where condition in entity framework for two or more different DbSets

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have two different DbSets. Now i want to query both DbSets like this:

```
Cars.Where(a => a.Attributes.Color.Name = "Red");
Horses.Where(a => a.Saddle.Attributes.Color.Name = "Black");
```

Is it possible to outsourcing the Attributes.Color.Name part in a Method without getting a "Not supported exception"? Like this:

```
Cars.Where(a => Reuse.CheckColor(a, "Red"));
Horses.Where(a => Reuse.CheckColor(a.Saddle, "Red"));
```

Comment: You could write an extension method for the classes this needs to apply to, but it will mostly likely be faster and require less code to continue with what you have now.

Comment: If you need to handle complex CRUDs for your entities, the best option is to create a wrapper for each entity: Repository and/or Unit of work. It will take more code but in the long run it will payback all the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` predicate is just a lambda expression (in the form of an expression tree), which you should be able to introduce as a local variable like so:

```
Expression<Func<MyAttributesClass, bool>> predicate = attribute => attribute.Color.Name == "Red";
```